# How to calculate correct number of integers from JSON array in file. C

Tags: c, arrays, json

I am given a text file with a JSON array in the following format: [100,200,300]
I am supposed to write a function which loads the contents of the JSON array (integers only) to a new array and returns a pointer to it. When I calculate the length it works for smaller values, large values (ie 100) are incorrect.A file with 100 elements will be calculated to have only 99. Here is my code.

```
intarr_t* intarr_load_json( const char* filename ){

FILE * fp = fopen(filename,"rb");

if (fp == NULL){
    return NULL;
}

fseek(fp,sizeof(int),SEEK_END);
int end = (int)ftell(fp);
printf("LENGTH OF FILE: %d\n",end);
rewind(fp);
int len = end/sizeof(int)-1;
intarr_t * new = intarr_create(len);
printf("LENGTH OF NEW ARRAY: %d\n",len);
int n;
char c;

fscanf(fp,"%c",&c);

for (int i=0;i<len;i++){
    fscanf(fp,"%d%c",&n,&c);
    new->data[i] = n;
}

fclose(fp);

return new;
}
```

Comment: If I understand your code correctly, you're trying to count how many integers the file could contain on your machine and based on that allocate the space for your array. JSON numbers are serialized text (kind of), and can vary in length quite a bit, so your calculations have been correct some of the times by sheer luck.

Comment: If your file only contains that array, you can iterate through it once, count the commas, and add one. Otherwise, I'd suggest using a dedicated JSON parsing library, since you'll basically need to write your own if you don't.

Comment: Counting the commas worked. Thanks!